# Beautifulsoup scraping specific table in page with multiple tables

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

results = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_multiple_Olympic_gold_medalists")

src = results.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

trs = soup.find_all("tr")
for tr in trs:
    print(tr.text)
```

This is the code I write for the scraping table from the page "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_multiple_Olympic_gold_medalists"

If I am only targeting the table in the session "List of most Olympic gold medals over career", how can I specify the table I need? There are 2 sortable `jquery-tablesorter` so I cannot use the class attribute to select the table I needed.

One more question, if I know that the page I am scraping contains a lot of tables and the one I need always have 10 `td` in 1 `row`, can I have something like

```
If len(td) == 10:
print(tr)
```

to extract the data I wanted

Update on code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

results = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_multiple_Olympic_gold_medalists")

src = results.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

tbs = soup.find("tbody")
trs = tbs.find_all("tr")
for tr in trs:
    print(tr.text)
```

I have one of the solution, not a good one, just to extract the first table from the page which is the one I needed, any suggestion/ improvement are welcomed!

Thank you.

Comment: it would be more like `len(soup.find_all('td'))`

Comment: Thank you, I am trying if it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only get the first table you can use a CSS Selector `nth-of-type(1)`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_multiple_Olympic_gold_medalists"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

table = soup.select_one("table.wikitable:nth-of-type(1)")
trs = table.find_all("tr")

for tr in trs:
    print(tr.text)
```